# Inserting rows at specific sections swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a lazy loaded pagination that was implanted on a UITableView and it works eg below

```
func reloadData(_ data: [Member], hasMore: Bool) {
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        let oldSize  = results.count
        results.append(contentsOf: data)
        let newSize = results.count
        var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        
        for count in 0 ..< ( newSize - oldSize ) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: count+oldSize, section: 0)
            indexPaths.append(indexPath)
        }
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .bottom)
        tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

The line of code above works for my tableView with a single section.

The problem I have now is I have another tableView with multiple section. The sections are basically dates that is members are grouped in a section of their creation date which is sent from the server.

How can I accommodate for this section in my code . Thanks

Comment: It depends on the exact data. I recommend a diffable data source. Group the members, create a new snapshot and apply it. By the way: delete `begin-/endUpdates()`. Both methods have no effect.

Comment: I cannot use a diffable data source because I have an iOS12 target.

Comment: You're hardcoding the section index here `let indexPath = IndexPath(row: count+oldSize, section: 0)`, you should figure out the section index based on the logic creating sections out of your `results` array

Answer (score 0):

You current code only works with single section with increasing members. For multiple sections or decreasing members, you code won't work. Below code talk only considers that the data is increasing.

1. order the data from the server by date (the order should be the same with the tableview's section)
2. for each of the data, check it belongs to any of the current section, if true, insert it to the section in right order. If false, create a new section in the right order and put it in.
3. in tableview, insert sections, insert rows.